# Why autocommit is by default false in Hibernate when we have the Transaction management apis provided?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I'm not getting a clear idea of why autocommit is by default false in Hibernate when we have the Transaction management apis provided.
I have three questions

1. why autocommit mode is not recommended by Hibernate?
2. What happens when we use autocommit = true and then use the Hibernate Transaction apis for transaction management ?
3. When using spring declarative transaction management how @Transactional(readonly = true) will help the read only code (Hibernate code) we write?

Comment: auto-commit would lead to each query committing itself, i.e. run outside a transaction. Now when you need to do 10 queries at once you want them all to fail or succeed. When using transactions auto commit will be switched of. When using readonly transactions hibernate will operate in readonly mode and not allow updates. A commit on the transaction and having pending changes will fail stating that you cannot update during a readonly transaction.

Comment: @M.Deinum So even if we are making autocommit = true. By using Transaction apis we can override the autocommit mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will answer one by one Starting with (2) as i don't know much about (1)

(2): autocommit=true means by default all queries get commited. In such case If

- if there is a @Transactional on a method, it overrides the autocommit and encloses all queries into a single transaction, thus overriding the autocommit
- if there is a @Transactional method that calls other @Transactional annotated methods, the outer most annotation should override the inner annotaions and create a larger transaction, thus annotations also override eachother.

(3): In DBs like Oracal/Mysql a read only transaction can be translated READ_ONLY level which provides no dirty reads, no unrepeatable reads but doesn’t allow any updates. That means the flush mode will be set as `FlushMode.NEVER` in the current Hibernate Session preventing the session from commiting the transaction. Even `setReadOnly(true)` will be called on the JDBC Connection which ensure that you cannot call session.flsuh() even to flush session manually.

since Spring doesn't do persistence itself, it cannot specify what readOnly should exactly mean. This attribute is only a hint to the provider, the behavior depends on, in this case, Hibernate.

Comment: So even if we are making autocommit = true. By using Transaction apis we can override the autocommit mode.

Comment: If  write a code to check your (2) point, you will find that when the spring uses this kind of way to do the transaction. If your config is that auto commit is true, then it will change it to false and after the transaction it will change it to true.

Comment: I guess something missing about (2) "if there is a Transactional on a method, it overrides the autocommit and encloses all queries into a single transaction, thus overriding the autocommit" UNLESS if you don't explicitly defined auto commit=true
So auto commit default mode is true if u left like that when Transactional method calls then the transaction will switch of auto commit.                           But if you explicitly declare auto-commit=true then transaction will not switch of auto commit.

Answer (score 1):

In regards of (1):

Suppose, you own a company and have 1000 employees. You maintain a database table to track if an employee was paid at the end of the month already or not.

So, here we are, the end of the month and pay day. Payroll sends you an excel file
with 600 names who has just received their compensation for the last month. So you log on to your computer and start your java app and select the excel to save all 600 records in your database. It usually takes 2 minutes, but now it fails at 1 minute and 23 second. What is your expectation now? Do you expect a partially uploaded file with gosh'knows how many records, or nothing at all? Your autocommit will drive it: If autocommit=false then you can give a go to upload the whole file again and again, but if autocommit=true you might need to tweak around your input data first to remove some records to prevent duplicates in your database.

I hope, my simplified example helps you to better understand it, but really the purpose is to ensure either everything from a batch is saved (it includes every write operation, like insert/update/delete) in the database or nothing at all in case an error occurs at anytime during the process. In the real life in most of the cases you and your organisation will expect complete data sets rather than partial data set in the database. Understanding it is key and anybody who advises to 'use autocommit=true because it is safe' should be avoided by miles. This is a key concept and one of the foundation of data management.